# Attribute node for Vertex color texturing problem

Tags: vertex-colors

I would like to use vertex color information for texturing. I found some description on the web but there is something what I can't figure out. If I use a color at 0.5 value, the FAC value through separate RGB node looks like not 0.5 result. What am I missing?[image]

Comment: If I disconnect node from FAC at mix shader and set the value manually to 0,5 I get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: I put a 'Gamma' node between the 'Attribute', and 'Separate RGB' with a Gamma setting of (1/2.2), that is to say,  (0.45454....) and it seemed to correct the 'Fac' in the mix. A proper answer would explain which color spaces get used down this pipeline, and justify the setting, so this is just a comment.

Comment: I found an answer from a _much_ more reliable source, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82441/vertex-colors-are-wrong-value)

Comment: The gamma node really helps, Thank you! The background of color spaces is "chinese" for me at first look, but maybe later I will learn about this.

Comment: It is confusing, because which spaces are used by which bits of the system is not always well documented.